# jQuery Datatables Ajax Call get's broken after first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a datatable:

```
var dt = $("#reservations").DataTable(
                {
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: "ReservationStart",
                            render: function (data) {
                                return $.format.date(data, "d MMM, yyyy h:mm a");
                            }

                        },
                        {
                            data: "Covers"
                        },
                        {
                            data: "id",
                            render: function (data) {
                                return "<button class='btn btn-primary js-edit' data-reservation-id=" + data + ">Edit</button> &nbsp; <button class='btn btn-secondary js-delete' data-reservation-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            );
```

The datatable is used to display a list of reservations for a customer. First the customer enters their email address, then I make an ajax call to retrieve their customer ID, then a second ajax call to populate the table with all reservations associated with their customer ID:

```
var baseURL = "/api/Reservations?CustomerId=";

$("#btnSearch").on("click",
            function () {
                var custEmail = $("#txtEmail").val();
                var customer = $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "/api/Customers?email=" + custEmail,
                        data: "",
                        success: function (customer) {
                            var ajaxurl = baseURL + customer.id;
                            var ajaxobj = {
                                url: ajaxurl,
                                dataSrc: ""
                            };
                            dt.ajax.url(ajaxobj).load();
                            dt.clear().draw();
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            bootbox.alert("Doesn't look like you've made any bookings.");
                        }
                    });
            });
```

After the page loads, this works perfectly. However, if you try to execute a second search, the URL for the ajax call to the reservations API gets changed from this:

http://localhost:55601/api/Reservations?CustomerId=1&_=1522265383241

to this:

http://localhost:55601/Reservations/[object%20Object]?_=1522265383242

I've researched `[object%20Object]` extensively, and it would seem to indicate a badly formatted ajax request. In some cases the url is malformed, in other cases specifying the http method fixes it. However, in my case neither of these seem to be the problem, and the weird thing is it works on the first run so I don't think this is it.

I've added some logging which shows what is happening:

[image]

As you can see, the customer API call is working fine every time. The URL getting sent to the ajax call for the reservations API is getting set correctly every time. The only thing I can see that's different on the first run is that 'data' is undefined.

Have I done something wrong here? Or is there a quirk in the way either jquery or the datatables plugin works that I haven't understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what the problem is. Normally, when you initialise your table, you specify an ajax object:

```
$("#mytable").DataTables({
    ajax:
    {
        url: [api url],
        dataSrc: [data source or blank]
    },
    columns:
    [
        etc...
    ]
});
```

In my case, because I don't have the data until the user executes the search, I haven't specified this (initialising the table with an ajax object without the url specified results in an undefined error). Therefore, when I first run the ajax call for the datatable (not for the customer search), I have to pass it an object. Passing it the URL only results in an undefined error.

However, on subsequent runs, as the ajax object is already defined at this point, passing an object as the URL parameter has the expected effect - the URL is an object hence the `[object%20Object]` we are seeing.

I had tried using the destroy() function previously to no effect. So, my workaround is simply to use an iteration counter. On the first run I pass it the object, on subsequent runs I pass it the URL.

I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing this.